# How do I tell if the value of a particular key in my dictionary is a dictionary so that I can solve programming questions based on this recursively?

Tags: python, dictionary, object

So I want to make sure that a particular value of key is a primitive data type i.e not a dictionary. If it is a dictionary, I want to recursively check till I reach the end. ( base case-: no dictionary in the values) Let's say I have this code

```
dict ={ 
    "Roll No" : "1",
    "Car"     : {
         "Ferrari"  : "12",
         "Pontiac"  : "15"`
     },
     "Budget" : "3"
   }
```

How do I get "Car" as the key which has the datatype of the values to be a dictionary?

And how do I access the sub-dictionary ?

```
{ "Car":{
    "Ferrari":"12",
   "Pontiac":"15"
   },
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `dict['Car']` ?

Comment: I dont think it would work. I mean I want  to do it recursively so if there's subdictionaries possible within Car then I'd be stuck? if Car can be it's own dictionary which I can access then it'd work!

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Actually dict['Car']  will be useful to get the values and check if they are in fact a dictionary and not a string. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's `type()` function to decide if the element is a dictionary, and thus when to recurse:

```
searchDictionary( haystack, needle ):
    for key in haystack.keys():
        if type( haystack[key] ) is dict:
            searchDictionary( haystack[key], needle )
        elif type( haystack[key] ) is str:
            # TODO - match string
            if ( haystack[key] == needle ):
                print( "Found at "+str(key) )
        elif type( haystack[key] ) is int:
            # TODO - match integer
            pass
```

There's a bunch of other ways to iterate over the dictionary, but I chose this method to illustrate the answer in a readable manner.